# Javascript - Multiple Unequal Random Number Generator

Tags: javascript, canvas, random, slice, splice

I am trying to write a function which produces four unequal random numbers in a given range, but the function is currently failing at the `while (selection[i] in selection.slice().splice(i)` line. This line should check whether the current (`i`'th) value is shared by any of the other random values but at the moment it seems to do nothing - perhaps I have used `in` incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated.

```
function contains(a, obj) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] === obj) {
    return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

selected=[];

function randomSelection() {

  var notselected=[];
  for (var i=0; i<25; i++) {
    if(!contains(selected, i)) {
        notselected.push(i);
    }
  }
  var selection=[notselected[Math.floor(Math.random() * notselected.length)],
                             notselected[Math.floor(Math.random() * notselected.length)],
                             notselected[Math.floor(Math.random() * notselected.length)],
                             notselected[Math.floor(Math.random() * notselected.length)]];

  for (var i=0; i<selection.length; i++) {
    while (selection[i] in selection.slice().splice(i)) {
      alert('Hello!')
      selection[i] = notselected[Math.floor(Math.random() * notselected.length)];
    }
  }
  for (var i=0; i<selection.length; i++) {
    selected.pop(selection[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain a random value between two numbers using the following method

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

If the value needs to be an integer you can use the following method:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

So, supposing that you need 4 different random integer values you could do something like that

```
var randoms = [];
while(randoms.length < 4) {

  var random = getRandomInt(0, 25);

  if(randoms.indexOf(random) === -1) {
    randoms.push(random);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To randomly shuffle a set of objects (numbers in this case)

```js
    var values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
    function shuffle(arr){
        var temp = [...arr];
        arr.length = 0;
        while(temp.length > 0){
            arr.push(temp.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * temp.length),1)[0]);
        }
        return arr;
    }
    console.log("pre shuffle : [" + values.join(", ") + "]"); 
    shuffle(values);
    console.log("post shuffle : [" + values.join(", ") + "]");
```